# Encrypting Data into a JPG file and uploading it to cloud photo hosting services

Tags: encryption, jpeg

Is there a tool or how would one encrypt data into a jpg file and be able to upload to photo hosting service? Has anyone done this with RAW image files as those can be much bigger and can hold more data. Another thing is has anyone done this to much larger files and span it across multiple jpg files?

Comment: Do you mean (1) taking a JPEG or raw or other image file, and encrypting its contents, or (2) taking arbitrary data (e.g., text and spreadsheets), encrypting it, and giving it a `.jpg` extension to fool the photo hosting service into accepting it (and thus adding a layer of “security through obscurity” to the encryption)?⁠

Comment: I don't understand the down votes? Why isn't this a valid question?

Comment: Well, I didn’t downvote it, but I believe that the question is ambiguous (as spelled out in my comment), and maybe other people do, too. Why don’t you [edit] the question and clarify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A basic example**

Original image:

[image]

Image with secret message:

[image]

There's no apparent difference when looking at the two images. However, if you drag the second one into a folder on your computer (or save some other way), and open it in a text editor such as Notepad, you will find the first paragraphs of the Wikipedia article included at the end of the image. I put the text there by editing the png with my favourite text editor (SciTE).

You could put encrypted data in the same spot rather than plain text, if you have a method of encrypting and unencrypting text.

If you want to use a fancier method of changing bits within the image while not being detectable, you'll need fancy software to do the writing and reading. Can't help you that, sorry, I don't work for a spy agency. But depending on your use case, something simple like this example may work for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is called [Steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) and dates back to 400BC. The answer is "yes," but you seem to attribute magical properties to file types as to somehow allow for "more information" to be contained in them, I can't think of any reason this would be so.

Comment: I will note however that JPG, being a lossy format, can mangle data. So presumably the hidden information would be applied in some way to post-compression data.